# Django One to Many Loose Relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

### Backstory

Data is being pulled from an accounting system that can have department, market, and client relationship data associated with it. The relationship data are all TEXT/CHAR fields. They are not integer columns. There are over 2 million rows.

### The problem

The problem I've been running into is how to add the lines without relationship validation that could fail because the related table (like Market) is missing the value or has been changed (because we are looking far back in the past). The naming of the columns in the Django database (more detail below), and querying Django models with a join that don't have a relationship attribute on the class.

#### models.py

```py
from typing import Optional

from django.db import models


class Line(models.Model):
    entry_number: int = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    posting_date: date = models.DateField()
    document_number: Optional[str] = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default=None)
    description: Optional[str] = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default=None)
    department: Optional[str] = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default=None)
    market: Optional[str] = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default=None)
    amount: Decimal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2)
    client: Optional[str] = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, default=None)

    # This relationship works
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='lines')


class Department(models.Model):
    code: str = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

class Market(models.Model):
    code: str = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

The data for the line is filled in the a sql statement grabbing the data from the accounting system.

### In SqlAlchemy

What I am looking for is something like this which can be represented in sqlalchemy.

```py
class Line(...):

    # snipped

    client_rel: Client = relationship("Client", primaryjoin=client == foreign(Client.code), viewonly=True)
    department_rel: Department = relationship("Department", primaryjoin=department == foreign(Department.code), viewonly=True)
    market_rel: Market = relationship("Market", primaryjoin=market == foreign(Market.code), viewonly=True)


# snipped the other related classes
```

The SQLAlchemy code allows for `primaryjoins` which are relationships only enforced at the python level not in the database. It also allows for the relatanship's loose foreign key to be named almost anything. As far as I can tell Django's foreign key column has to be `"name"_id` and can't be changed.

Comment: on the foreign key  add null=True , blank = True  create a new migration to the database

Comment: How does this help with querying for classes that don't have a foreign key relationship? If that is how the foreign key would be added how would it effect the data that is already in  `Line`?

Comment: ok , sorry i did a wrong comment